# PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer can't resolve property

Tags: spring

I am reading document here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-value-annotations

```
@Component
public class MovieRecommender {

    private final String catalog;

    public MovieRecommender(@Value("${catalog.name}") String catalog) {
        this.catalog = catalog;
    }
}

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig { }
```

And the following application.properties file:

```
catalog.name=MovieCatalog
```

> A default lenient embedded value resolver is provided by Spring. It
> will try to resolve the property value and if it cannot be resolved,
> the property name (for example ${catalog.name}) will be injected as
> the value.

What does "it cannot be resolved" mean? If I don't have this property in the application.properties, it gives me error:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'catalog.name' in value "${catalog.name}"
```

**Updated**:

I figured it out. In Spring core, if property not found, it uses ${catalog.name}

But in SpringBoot, if property not found, it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve means find. Sometime the resolution (finding) can be complicated.

An SpringBoot each property in application properties can also be injected with an environment variable. So catalog.name could be left out of apllication.properties and used as env var CATALOG_NAME.

AFAIK a value can also come in on a command line.